# IBAN Validation check

Tags: javascript, iban

I need to do an IBAN validation check using JavaScript. The rules I need to follow are:

**Validating the IBAN**
An IBAN is validated by converting it into an integer and performing a basic mod-97 operation (as described in ISO 7064) on it. If the IBAN is valid, the remainder equals 1.

1. Check that the total IBAN length is correct as per the country. If not, the IBAN is invalid
2. Move the four initial characters to the end of the string
3. Replace each letter in the string with two digits, thereby expanding the string, where A = 10, B = 11, ..., Z = 35
4. Interpret the string as a decimal integer and compute the remainder of that number on division by 97

I am doing this for a Belarusian IBAN so it has to follow the following format

2C 31N -

RU1230000000000000000000000000000

How do I modify the following to meet the above rules;

```js
function validateIBAN(iban) {
  var newIban = iban.toUpperCase(),
    modulo = function(divident, divisor) {
      var cDivident = '';
      var cRest = '';

      for (var i in divident) {
        var cChar = divident[i];
        var cOperator = cRest + '' + cDivident + '' + cChar;

        if (cOperator < parseInt(divisor)) {
          cDivident += '' + cChar;
        } else {
          cRest = cOperator % divisor;
          if (cRest == 0) {
            cRest = '';
          }
          cDivident = '';
        }

      }
      cRest += '' + cDivident;
      if (cRest == '') {
        cRest = 0;
      }
      return cRest;
    };

  if (newIban.search(/^[A-Z]{2}/gi) < 0) {
    return false;
  }

  newIban = newIban.substring(4) + newIban.substring(0, 4);

  newIban = newIban.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(match) {
    return match.charCodeAt(0) - 55;
  });

  return parseInt(modulo(newIban, 97), 10) === 1;
}


console.log(validateIBAN("RU1230000000000000000000000000000"));
```

Answer (score 61):

Based on the work of http://toms-cafe.de/iban/iban.js I have developed my version of an IBAN validation check.

You can modify the country support by modifying the variable `CODE_LENGTHS`.

Here is my implementation:

```js
function alertValidIBAN(iban) {
    alert(isValidIBANNumber(iban));
}

/*
 * Returns 1 if the IBAN is valid 
 * Returns FALSE if the IBAN's length is not as should be (for CY the IBAN Should be 28 chars long starting with CY )
 * Returns any other number (checksum) when the IBAN is invalid (check digits do not match)
 */
function isValidIBANNumber(input) {
    var CODE_LENGTHS = {
        AD: 24, AE: 23, AT: 20, AZ: 28, BA: 20, BE: 16, BG: 22, BH: 22, BR: 29,
        CH: 21, CR: 21, CY: 28, CZ: 24, DE: 22, DK: 18, DO: 28, EE: 20, ES: 24,
        FI: 18, FO: 18, FR: 27, GB: 22, GI: 23, GL: 18, GR: 27, GT: 28, HR: 21,
        HU: 28, IE: 22, IL: 23, IS: 26, IT: 27, JO: 30, KW: 30, KZ: 20, LB: 28,
        LI: 21, LT: 20, LU: 20, LV: 21, MC: 27, MD: 24, ME: 22, MK: 19, MR: 27,
        MT: 31, MU: 30, NL: 18, NO: 15, PK: 24, PL: 28, PS: 29, PT: 25, QA: 29,
        RO: 24, RS: 22, SA: 24, SE: 24, SI: 19, SK: 24, SM: 27, TN: 24, TR: 26,   
        AL: 28, BY: 28, CR: 22, EG: 29, GE: 22, IQ: 23, LC: 32, SC: 31, ST: 25,
        SV: 28, TL: 23, UA: 29, VA: 22, VG: 24, XK: 20
    };
    var iban = String(input).toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/g, ''), // keep only alphanumeric characters
            code = iban.match(/^([A-Z]{2})(\d{2})([A-Z\d]+)$/), // match and capture (1) the country code, (2) the check digits, and (3) the rest
            digits;
    // check syntax and length
    if (!code || iban.length !== CODE_LENGTHS[code[1]]) {
        return false;
    }
    // rearrange country code and check digits, and convert chars to ints
    digits = (code[3] + code[1] + code[2]).replace(/[A-Z]/g, function (letter) {
        return letter.charCodeAt(0) - 55;
    });
    // final check
    return mod97(digits) === 1;
}

function mod97(string) {
    var checksum = string.slice(0, 2), fragment;
    for (var offset = 2; offset < string.length; offset += 7) {
        fragment = String(checksum) + string.substring(offset, offset + 7);
        checksum = parseInt(fragment, 10) % 97;
    }
    return checksum;
}
```

```css
input { width:300px; }
```

```html
Enter IBAN 
<input type="test" id="iban"/>
<button onclick="alertValidIBAN(document.getElementById('iban').value);">check IBAN</button>
```

Comment: Seems to work great. Added some more country codes and since it's a validate method I guess it should return boolean not the checksum value. So I also changed the return to be `return mod97(digits) === 1;`

Comment: @Ismaestro no, it returns '55' - > which as per description 'Returns any other number (checksum) when the IBAN is invalid'

Comment: Checked sniippet with account real, don't run correctly. Use  https://github.com/arhs/iban.js solution

Comment: Is it correct 'CR' is mentioned twice in the 'CODE_LENGTHS' list? See column 2 and 3.

Comment: CR is 22, not 21 (presumed costa rica)

Comment: The snippet returns for each IBAN [even correct] always `false`. DE12500105170648489890

Comment: `alertValidIBAN(null)` from snippet always returns false as it does not read the input field.

Comment: CR key is present twice in the CODE_LENGTHS object

Comment: Could you also set the checksum initially to 0 (zero) and start from offset = 0? (In my opinion it would reduce the (read) complexity of the mod97 function)

Comment: Checknumber values 00, 01 and 99 like in GB01BARC20714583608387 are invalid, but the algorithm doesn't check them

Answer (score 36):

You can use this library to validate and format an IBAN: https://github.com/arhs/iban.js (disclaimer: I wrote the library)

However, neither Russia nor Belarus are supported, as I can't find any mention of those countries on the [IBAN page of wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#IBAN_formats_by_country) nor in the [official IBAN registry](http://www.swift.com/dsp/resources/documents/IBAN_Registry.pdf) so I'm afraid you'll have to modify the library code yourself to add it.

Comment: this code cannot validate Moldovan IBAN. for example `MD75EX0900002374642125EU`. according to www.iban.com it is valid

Comment: Thanks @armen. Issue open (https://github.com/arhs/iban.js/issues/23) will fix it soon.

Comment: very nice @Laurent VB, is there any mailing list to inform me after this fix ?

Comment: @armen you can subscribe to the github issue notifications. I'll also come and keep this SO thread updated.

Answer (score 13):

I answered a similar question. Use this list of Regular expressions to validate your IBANS. There are 70 countries, so in general you should be good to go.

```
AL[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
AD[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){3}\s?
AT[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
AZ[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
BH[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){3}([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})\s?
BY[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
BE[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){3}\s?
BA[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
BR[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}([0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z]{1}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\s?
BG[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})\s?
CR[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}([0-9]{2})\s?
HR[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}([0-9]{1})\s?
CY[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
CZ[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
DK[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\s?
DO[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
TL[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}([0-9]{3})\s?
EE[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
FO[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\s?
FI[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\s?
FR[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){2}([0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})([0-9]{2})\s?
GE[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}\s?)([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\s?
DE[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}([0-9]{2})\s?
GI[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){3}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\s?
GR[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){3}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\s?
GL[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\s?
GT[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
HU[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){6}\s?
IS[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}([0-9]{2})\s?
IE[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\s?
IL[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}([0-9]{3})\s?
IT[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{1})([0-9]{3}\s?)([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\s?
JO[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){5}([0-9]{2})\s?
KZ[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})\s?
XK[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){2}([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}\s?)\s?
KW[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){5}([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})\s?
LV[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){3}([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\s?
LB[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
LI[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\s?
LT[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
LU[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){3}\s?
MK[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})([0-9]{2})\s?
MT[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){3}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\s?
MR[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}([0-9]{3})\s?
MU[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){4}([0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z]{1}\s?)([a-zA-Z]{2})\s?
MC[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){2}([0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})([0-9]{2})\s?
MD[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
ME[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}([0-9]{2})\s?
NL[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){2}([0-9]{2})\s?
NO[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){2}([0-9]{3})\s?
PK[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
PS[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){5}([0-9]{1})\s?
PL[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){6}\s?
PT[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}([0-9]{1})\s?
QA[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){5}([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\s?
RO[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
SM[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{1})([0-9]{3}\s?)([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\s?
SA[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
RS[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){4}([0-9]{2})\s?
SK[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
SI[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{3})\s?
ES[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
SE[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
CH[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})\s?
TN[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){5}\s?
TR[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\s?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){3}([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})\s?
AE[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{3})([0-9]{1}\s?)([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{3})\s?
GB[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\s?
VA[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([0-9]{3})([0-9]{1}\s?)([0-9]{4}\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\s?
VG[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?){1}([0-9]{4}\s?){4}\s?
```

Comment: The list contains IBAN regex for 70 countries. The IBANs are readily tested. Does the 3 downvotes mean, these IBANs are not useful ?

Comment: Upvoted because I found it useful but it seems to be not correct at all: I think after first two characters always 2 digits should follow. so instead of e.g. `AL[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}` it should be `AL[0-9]{2}` right!?

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. you are right, My B. I had added "c" instead of "n" in my tests for AL IBANs so according to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number it should be 8**n**,16c.

Comment: Just to be clear: it's not only for AL it affects all IBANs. Your quoted wikipedia says that IBAN consists ob 2 letter country code, followed by 2 (check)digits (always numeric) and then up to 30 alphanumeric characters that are country-specific. So the first block ´[a-zA-Z0-9]´should always just be ´[0-9]´

Comment: Thank you. You are right the first block is always [0-9] but the rest should remain the same.

Comment: Upvoted, because I needed regex for one country, not a general one.

Answer (score 7):

"Jquery validation plugin" also supports iban check:

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/additional/iban.js

Answer (score 7):

Based on previous answers I created a `Directive` that implements Angular `Validator` method.
I also added the types.

iban-validator.directive.ts

```
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ibanValidators]',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: IbanValidatorDirective,
    multi: true
  }]
})

export class IbanValidatorDirective implements Validator {

  validate(control: AbstractControl): object {
    const codeLengths = {
      AD: 24, AE: 23, AL: 28, AT: 20, AZ: 28, BA: 20, BE: 16, BG: 22, BH: 22, BR: 29, CH: 21, CR: 21, CY: 28, CZ: 24,
      DE: 22, DK: 18, DO: 28, EE: 20, ES: 24, LC: 30, FI: 18, FO: 18, FR: 27, GB: 22, GI: 23, GL: 18, GR: 27, GT: 28,
      HR: 21, HU: 28, IE: 22, IL: 23, IS: 26, IT: 27, JO: 30, KW: 30, KZ: 20, LB: 28, LI: 21, LT: 20, LU: 20, LV: 21,
      MC: 27, MD: 24, ME: 22, MK: 19, MR: 27, MT: 31, MU: 30, NL: 18, NO: 15, PK: 24, PL: 28, PS: 29, PT: 25, QA: 29,
      RO: 24, RS: 22, SA: 24, SE: 24, SI: 19, SK: 24, SM: 27, TN: 24, TR: 26
    };
    if (control.value) {
      const iban = control.value.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/g, '');
      const code = iban.match(/^([A-Z]{2})(\d{2})([A-Z\d]+)$/);
      let digits: number;
      if (!code || iban.length !== codeLengths[code[1]]) {
        return { ibanValid: false };
      }
      digits = (code[3] + code[1] + code[2]).replace(/[A-Z]/g, (letter: string) => {
        return letter.charCodeAt(0) - 55;
      });
      return this.mod97(digits) === 1 ? null : { ibanValid: false };
    }
  }

  private mod97(digital: number | string) {
    digital = digital.toString();
    let checksum: number | string = digital.slice(0, 2);
    let fragment = '';
    for (let offset = 2; offset < digital.length; offset += 7) {
      fragment = checksum + digital.substring(offset, offset + 7);
      checksum = parseInt(fragment, 10) % 97;
    }
    return checksum;
  }
}
```

Then just use the directive on an input.

Comment: Thanks for providing this copy-paste ready code snippet!

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old topic, but since it showed up on #1 place on Google, and since the solutions here aren't really refined I would like to show you my take on it:

```
export const validIban = (value) => {
    let rearrange =
        value.substring(4, value.length)
        + value.substring(0, 4);
    let alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split('');
    let alphaMap = {};
    let number = [];

    alphabet.forEach((value, index) => {
        alphaMap[value] = index + 10;
    });

    rearrange.split('').forEach((value, index) => {
        number[index] = alphaMap[value] || value;
    });

    return modulo(number.join('').toString(), 97) === 1;
}

const modulo = (aNumStr, aDiv) => {
    var tmp = "";
    var i, r;
    for (i = 0; i < aNumStr.length; i++) {
        tmp += aNumStr.charAt(i);
        r = tmp % aDiv;
        tmp = r.toString();
    }
    return tmp / 1;
}
```

It works pretty well for me you can test it with
`validIban(testThis)` / http://randomiban.com

Comment: This needs some refactor, must not work with '01', '1' and like.

Comment: Best solution by far without requiring any dependencies. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I wrote 2 regexes, the first one is for SEPA-only countries, the other is for all countries that support IBAN, as of 2021-10.

### IBAN regex for within-SEPA area countries

The first one checks if an IBAN is valid within the SEPA area, **the IBAN must belong to a country that is within the SEPA area**. (it considers IBAN outside the SEPA area as invalid)

```
^(?:((?:IT|SM)\d{2}[A-Z]{1}\d{22})|(NL\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{10})|(LV\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{13})|((?:BG|GB|IE)\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{14})|(GI\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{15})|(RO\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{16})|(MT\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{23})|(NO\d{13})|((?:DK|FI)\d{16})|((?:SI)\d{17})|((?:AT|EE|LU|LT)\d{18})|((?:HR|LI|CH)\d{19})|((?:DE|VA)\d{20})|((?:AD|CZ|ES|MD|SK|SE)\d{22})|(PT\d{23})|((?:IS)\d{24})|((?:BE)\d{14})|((?:FR|MC|GR)\d{25})|((?:PL|HU|CY)\d{26}))$
```

**Specifications**:

- https://www.iban.com/structure
- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1376mu58jQ2P5jGX7tIXGrFfwgfo0RHO7RBRSpKcViIs/edit?usp=sharing Google Sheet based on the above data structure, easier to work with

**Testing**:
https://regex101.com/r/oLRltj/1/

### IBAN regex for any country

```
^(?:(?:CR|DE|ME|RS|VA)\d{20}|(?:CZ|ES|SE|SK|TN)\d{22}|(?:DK|FI|FO|GL|SD)\d{16}|(?:AT|BA|EE|LT|XK)\d{18}|(?:AE|IL|TL)\d{21}|(?:LY|PT|ST)\d{23}|(?:IT|SM)\d{2}[A-Z]\d{10}[A-Za-z0-9]{12}|(?:HU|PL)\d{26}|(?:AL|CY)\d{10}[A-Za-z0-9]{16}|(?:CH|LI)\d{7}[A-Za-z0-9]{12}|(?:FR|MC)\d{12}[A-Za-z0-9]{11}\d{2}|(?:GB|IE)\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{14}|(?:KZ|LU)\d{5}[A-Za-z0-9]{13}|(?:GI|IQ)\d{2}[A-Z]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{15}|(?:PK|RO)\d{2}[A-Z]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{16}|(?:PS|QA)\d{2}[A-Z]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{21}|AD\d{10}[A-Za-z0-9]{12}|AZ\d{2}[A-Z]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{20}|BE\d{14}|BG\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{6}[A-Za-z0-9]{8}|BH\d{2}[A-Z]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{14}|BR\d{25}[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]|BY\d{2}[A-Za-z0-9]{4}\d{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{16}|DO\d{2}[A-Za-z0-9]{4}\d{20}|EG\d{27}|GE\d{2}[A-Z]\d{16}|GT\d{2}[A-Za-z0-9]{24}|GR\d{9}[A-Za-z0-9]{16}|HR\d{19}|IS\d{24}|JO\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{18}|KW\d{2}[A-Z]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{22}|LC\d{2}[A-Z]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{24}|LB\d{6}[A-Za-z0-9]{20}|LV\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{13}|MD\d{2}[A-Za-z0-9]{20}|MK\d{5}[A-Za-z0-9]{10}\d{2}|MR\d{25}|MT\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{5}[A-Za-z0-9]{18}|MU\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{19}[A-Z]{3}|NL\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{10}|NO\d{13}|SA\d{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{18}|SC\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{20}[A-Z]{3}|SI\d{17}|SV\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{20}|TR\d{8}[A-Za-z0-9]{16}|UA\d{8}[A-Za-z0-9]{19}|VG\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{16}|GE\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{16})$
```

This second regex was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69068004/2391795, and slightly modified to add proper support for GE (Georgia) country.

**Testing**:
https://regex101.com/r/I3oiuo/1/

Comment: Georgia's IBAN like `GE82517219517812137884` doesn't work.

Comment: Egypt's ones like `EG7194356565899151369854425` doesn't either. You can generate random ones with: http://randomiban.com/?country=Egypt.

Comment: I suggest if you find errors in those regexes, to use the https://regex101.com/r/I3oiuo/1/, duplicate it, and provide a fix (and tests!) for your country. This way it will keep becoming better and more accurate. If you do so, I'll use your newer regex101 link in the main answer, while keeping a history of changes for transparency. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Copy/Paste ready Typescript code for all countries mentioned [here](https://www.iban.com/structure):

```
function validateIban(input: string) {
  const codeLengths = {
    AD: 24,
    AE: 23,
    AL: 28,
    AT: 20,
    AZ: 28,
    BA: 20,
    BE: 16,
    BG: 22,
    BH: 22,
    BI: 28,
    BR: 29,
    BY: 28,
    CH: 21,
    CR: 22,
    CY: 28,
    CZ: 24,
    DE: 22,
    DK: 18,
    DO: 28,
    EE: 20,
    EG: 29,
    ES: 24,
    LC: 32,
    FI: 18,
    FO: 18,
    FR: 27,
    GB: 22,
    GE: 22,
    GI: 23,
    GL: 18,
    GR: 27,
    GT: 28,
    HR: 21,
    HU: 28,
    IE: 22,
    IL: 23,
    IQ: 23,
    IS: 26,
    IT: 27,
    JO: 30,
    KW: 30,
    KZ: 20,
    LB: 28,
    LI: 21,
    LT: 20,
    LU: 20,
    LV: 21,
    LY: 25,
    MC: 27,
    MD: 24,
    ME: 22,
    MK: 19,
    MR: 27,
    MT: 31,
    MU: 30,
    NL: 18,
    NO: 15,
    PK: 24,
    PL: 28,
    PS: 29,
    PT: 25,
    QA: 29,
    RO: 24,
    RS: 22,
    SA: 24,
    SC: 31,
    SD: 18,
    SE: 24,
    SI: 19,
    SK: 24,
    SM: 27,
    ST: 25,
    SV: 28,
    TL: 23,
    TN: 24,
    TR: 26,
    UA: 29,
    VA: 22,
    VG: 24,
    XK: 20,
  };
  const iban = input.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/g, "");
  const code = iban.match(/^([A-Z]{2})(\d{2})([A-Z\d]+)$/);
  if (!code || iban.length !== (codeLengths as any)[code[1]]) {
    return false;
  }
  const digits = (code[3] + code[1] + code[2]).replace(/[A-Z]/g, (letter: string) => {
    return (letter.charCodeAt(0) - 55).toString();
  });
  return mod97(digits) === 1;
}
```

and the checksum:

```
function mod97(digital: number | string) {
  digital = digital.toString();
  let checksum: number | string = digital.slice(0, 2);
  let fragment = "";
  for (let offset = 2; offset < digital.length; offset += 7) {
    fragment = checksum + digital.substring(offset, offset + 7);
    checksum = parseInt(fragment, 10) % 97;
  }
  return checksum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Just using this website api :  go to https://api.ibanapi.com and get
> apk_key
>
> ```
> iban    = SA4705000068203056854000
> api_key = ea649b36c1d1648bf0f12df82a8da475e2ee3447
> url     = 'https://api.ibanapi.com/v1/validate/'iban+'?api_key='+api_key+''
> ```
>
> **The IBAN Checker**
>
> - Check the structure of the IBAN and prepare it for the validation    engine
> - Make sure the country supports the IBAN as per the Swift public registery
> - Validate the IBAN using the check digits.
> - If the country level validation is supported, it will run through it
> - Get the bank information for this IBAN from our registery

Answer (score 0):

Based on the last SWIFT IBAN Registrar publication (June 2021), available [here](https://www.swift.com/resource/iban-registry-pdf), I updated Rony Nasr's REGEX proposal. It includes 79 countries and checks country-specific IBAN structure and length. (It does NOT, however, do a checksum MOD97 verification).

```
/^(?:(?:CR|DE|ME|RS|VA)\d{20}|(?:CZ|ES|SE|SK|TN)\d{22}|(?:DK|FI|FO|GL|SD)\d{16}|(?:AT|BA|EE|LT|XK)\d{18}|(?:AE|IL|TL)\d{21}|(?:LY|PT|ST)\d{23}|(?:IT|SM)\d{2}[A-Z]\d{10}[A-Za-z0-9]{12}|(?:HU|PL)\d{26}|(?:AL|CY)\d{10}[A-Za-z0-9]{16}|(?:CH|LI)\d{7}[A-Za-z0-9]{12}|(?:FR|MC)\d{12}[A-Za-z0-9]{11}\d{2}|(?:GB|IE)\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{14}|(?:KZ|LU)\d{5}[A-Za-z0-9]{13}|(?:GI|IQ)\d{2}[A-Z]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{15}|(?:PK|RO)\d{2}[A-Z]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{16}|(?:PS|QA)\d{2}[A-Z]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{21}|AD\d{10}[A-Za-z0-9]{12}|AZ\d{2}[A-Z]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{20}|BE\d{14}|BG\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{6}[A-Za-z0-9]{8}|BH\d{2}[A-Z]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{14}|BR\d{25}[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]|BY\d{2}[A-Za-z0-9]{4}\d{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{16}|DO\d{2}[A-Za-z0-9]{4}\d{20}|EG\d{27}|GE\d{2}[A-Z]\d{16}|GT\d{2}[A-Za-z0-9]{24}|GR\d{9}[A-Za-z0-9]{16}|HR\d{19}|IS\d{24}|JO\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{18}|KW\d{2}[A-Z]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{22}|LC\d{2}[A-Z]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{24}|LB\d{6}[A-Za-z0-9]{20}|LV\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{13}|MD\d{2}[A-Za-z0-9]{20}|MK\d{5}[A-Za-z0-9]{10}\d{2}|MR\d{25}|MT\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{5}[A-Za-z0-9]{18}|MU\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{19}[A-Z]{3}|NL\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{10}|NO\d{13}|SA\d{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{18}|SC\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{20}[A-Z]{3}|SI\d{17}|SV\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{20}|TR\d{8}[A-Za-z0-9]{16}|UA\d{8}[A-Za-z0-9]{19}|VG\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{16}|GE\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{16})$/gm
```

Comment: You're missing the GE country.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918217/the-mod97-operation-in-iban-validation, this should be pretty straightforward. No need to overcomplicate or use regular expressions.

Here's what I came up with:

```
const mod97 = str => {
  const first9 = str.substring(0, 9);
  const remainingStr = str.substring(9);
  const remainder = Number(first9) % 97;
  const newString = remainder.toString() + remainingStr;

  if (newString.length > 2) {
    return mod97(newString);
  }

  return remainder;
};

const validateIBAN = iban => {
  const reorderedString = iban.substring(4) + iban.substring(0, 4);
  const replacedString = reorderedString.replaceAll(/[a-z]{1}/gi, match =>
    (match.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) - 55).toString(),
  );

  return mod97(replacedString) === 1;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

I have managed to create the below RegEx for quick validation based on the current format.

```
/^(?:(?:IT|SM)\d{2}[A-Z]\d{22}|NL\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{10}|RO\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d[A-Z]\d{14}|LV\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{13}|FR\d{19}[A-Z]\d{5}|LI\d{17}[A-Z]{2}|MD\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{18}|(?:BG|GB|IE)\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{14}|BH\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{10}[A-Z]{2}\d{2}|GE\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{16}|GI\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{15}|BR\d{25}[A-Z]\d|MU\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{19}[A-Z]{3}|PS\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{21}|QA\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{14}[A-Z]{7}|(?:AZ|DO|GT)\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{20}|(?:BJ|ML|SN|CI)\d{2}[A-Z]\d{23}|(?:PK|VG)\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{16}|(?:KW|JO)\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{22}|MT\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{12}[A-Z]{7}\d{3}[A-Z]|NO\d{13}|(?:BE|BI)\d{14}|(?:DK|FI|GL|FO)\d{16}|(?:MK|SI)\d{17}|(?:BA|LT|AT|EE|KZ|LU|XK)\d{18}|(?:HR|CH|CR)\d{19}|(?:DE|ME|RS)\d{20}|(?:AE|IL|TL)\d{21}|(?:AD|CZ|ES|SA|DZ|SK|SE|TN)\d{22}|(?:PT|AO|CV|MZ)\d{23}|(?:IS|IR|TR)\d{24}|(?:MR|MC|BF|CM|GR|MG)\d{25}|(?:AL|DO|LB|PL|CY|HU)\d{26})$/i
```

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't validate IBAN.